# Rules to remove user from role on node publish

Tags: 7, nodes, users, rules

I have tried the following:

- Event: updating an existing content
- condition: NOT node-unchanged published
- remove user role (I'm stuck here)

The last item is my problem. There is no user reference in the data selector field, it just has site and node items and even the node items has nothing related to the node's field. It just has stuff like status, vid, uid, comments, nothing referring to the nodes field items.

What I think I need is to select Romove user role, I select the user from the data selector and then select the role it needs to be removed from.

DETAILS ON CONTENT TYPE
The content type provides field for two email addresses to be provided by the node author - the node status at this time is unpublished. The two emails are then used to create new user accounts (with notification to the email owners) which are added to specific roles (these are done with rules). The two new accounts are granted permission (via the field permission module) to provide values to corresponding fields in the same content type. When the two users update the node by providing the values, the admin changes the status of the node to published.

Once unpublished the two new users need to be removed from the respective roles, though they remain authenticated users.

Thank you for looking into this

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the rule on updating node and by setting the following  conditions:

1. that the current-user is not an admin nor the node author
2. that updated node status is published
3. that the corresponding form field is not empty

THen the action is set to remove user role of current-user from [desire_role]